# Does Preview for Developers Apply to All Phones?

Tags: developer-preview

I want to sign up my Lumia 1020 with the [Preview for Developers](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/preview-for-developers/178ac8a1-6519-4a0b-960c-038393741e96). If I do this, will it automatically apply to all of my phones associated with that Microsoft account, or does it apply to the 1020 only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the Developer Preview app on your phone and sign into it with your Microsoft Account. http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=178ac8a1-6519-4a0b-960c-038393741e96 
So only phones with this app installed will receive dev preview updates.
You then still have the option to not install available preview updates.